Importing Swift into Objective-C with CMake
I have a QT app with CMake. CMake generates .xcodeproj and CocoaPods generates .xcworkspace from the following Podfile:
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, :deployment_target => '14.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters'
  pod 'YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters'
  pod 'YandexMobileAdsMediation'
  pod 'YandexMobileAdsInstream'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
    end
  end
end

pod install command generates the following headers:
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters-umbrella.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters-Swift.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters.xcframework/ios-arm64/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters-umbrella.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters.xcframework/ios-arm64/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsIronSourceAdapters-Swift.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAds/static/YandexMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/YandexMobileAds.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAds-umbrella.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAds/static/YandexMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/YandexMobileAds.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAds-Swift.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAds/static/YandexMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/YandexMobileAds.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAds.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAds/static/YandexMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64/YandexMobileAds.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAds-umbrella.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAds/static/YandexMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64/YandexMobileAds.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAds-Swift.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAds/static/YandexMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64/YandexMobileAds.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAds.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsInstream/YandexMobileAdsInstream.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/YandexMobileAdsInstream.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsInstreamVersion.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsInstream/YandexMobileAdsInstream.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/YandexMobileAdsInstream.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsInstream-Swift.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsInstream/YandexMobileAdsInstream.xcframework/ios-arm64/YandexMobileAdsInstream.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsInstreamVersion.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsInstream/YandexMobileAdsInstream.xcframework/ios-arm64/YandexMobileAdsInstream.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsInstream-Swift.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters-Swift.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters-umbrella.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters.xcframework/ios-arm64/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters-Swift.h
./Pods/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters.xcframework/ios-arm64/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters.framework/Headers/YandexMobileAdsAdMobAdapters-umbrella.h

but I can't include them into .mm file in my project. I tried various paths like
#import <YandexMobileAds.h>
#import <YandexMobileAds/YandexMobileAds-Swift.h>
#import <YandexMobileAds/YandexMobileAds.h>

but without a success:


Why aren't they found?

My first Idea was to make them public somehow, but I did not find Header section on Build Phases page:

(there are a lot of tasks like Generate .rcc/qmlcache .. , but not Headers).

XCode shows the following Pods among others:


Another question is why YandexMobileAdsMediation header is not generated? (but only YandexMobileAds)

See Yandex docs on how to use their packages from a Swift project.

Is it possible to add Swift packages to a project with CMake? (It is possible to link against a Swift library, but what about a Swift package?)

EDIT1:
I do not understand Objective-C syntax well enough, but at least I was able to find required class name InterstitialAdLoader in generated YandexMobileAds-Swift.h header and I can assume that it is defined here:
grep -ri "InterstitialAdLoader" . --include=\*.h

./YandexMobileAds-Swift.h:@protocol YMAInterstitialAdLoaderDelegate;
./YandexMobileAds-Swift.h:SWIFT_CLASS_NAMED("InterstitialAdLoader")
./YandexMobileAds-Swift.h:@interface YMAInterstitialAdLoader : NSObject
./YandexMobileAds-Swift.h:@property (nonatomic, weak) id <YMAInterstitialAdLoaderDelegate> _Nullable delegate;
./YandexMobileAds-Swift.h:SWIFT_PROTOCOL_NAMED("InterstitialAdLoaderDelegate")
./YandexMobileAds-Swift.h:@protocol YMAInterstitialAdLoaderDelegate <NSObject>
./YandexMobileAds-Swift.h:/// \param adLoader A reference to an object of the <code>InterstitialAdLoader</code> class that invoked the method.
./YandexMobileAds-Swift.h:- (void)interstitialAdLoader:(YMAInterstitialAdLoader * _Nonnull)adLoader didLoad:(YMAInterstitialAd * _Nonnull)interstitialAd;
./YandexMobileAds-Swift.h:/// \param adLoader A reference to an object of the <code>InterstitialAdLoader</code> class that invoked the method.
./YandexMobileAds-Swift.h:- (void)interstitialAdLoader:(YMAInterstitialAdLoader * _Nonnull)adLoader didFailToLoadWithError:(YMAAdRequestError * _Nonnull)error;

so theoretically including YandexMobileAds-Swift.h to my .mm file can be step to a right direction.

I changed Podfile with this:
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, :deployment_target => '14.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'YandexMobileAdsMediation', '7.5.1'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
    end
  end
end

and was able to compile my .mm file with
#import <YandexMobileAds/YandexMobileAds-Swift.h>

But I still do not understand well enough what this Podfile does.
